# Symfony Process pgrep fails

Tags: php, bash, laravel, symfony, docker

Here's my code(Laravel)

```
$process= new Symfony\Component\Process\Process("pgrep java");
try {
    $process->mustRun();
} catch (ProcessFailedException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
return $process->getOutput();
```

it fails. When I try `pgrep --help` it succeeds. I tried this when java is running and not. This is the error:
[image]

I also use Docker by the way, and I've already tried: `docker-compose exec workspace bash` and `cd` to `/var/www/laravel/public` and executed `pgrep java` both when java is running and not. When java is running, as expected, it outputs the PID. `pkill java` also doesn't work. I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgrep xxxx` will set a status code accordingly to whether or not `xxxx` is a running process, this is a useful to check if a process is running:

```
if pgrep xxxx; then
  ...
```

In your case it seams to get Symfony to complain. Chaining the processes might help:

```
pgrep java || true
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand. but the problem is, even if there's a process 'java' running (i checked it via terminal), running this symfony process won't return anything and fails.

Comment: accepting this answer since this is correct, it seems that the problem of this question is related to docker.